# Get FFMPEG KeyFrames Time or time range

Tags: video, time, ffmpeg

I am using the following command to get keyframe of desire video

```sh
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf select='eq(pict_type\,I)',setpts='N/(24*TB)' %09d.jpg
```

I want to extract key-frame time/time duration/start time-end time to map keyframe with time.

Is there any way to get time information of key-frame in the same command?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the following command does what you want, for my application it works:

```sh
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf select=key -an -vsync 0 \ 
       keyframes%03d.jpeg -loglevel debug 2>&1 |
grep select:1 > keyframes.txt
```

Replace `grep` with `findstr` if you're under Windows.

Comment: I need to change the select option to **select="eq(pict_type\,I)"** for it to work

Comment: @Gobe, in your code, is there a way to get only `keyframes.txt` and not the actual frames in temp folder. I found ffmpeg to be faster to get the timestamp of keyframes rather than ffprobe. but i don't want to save the keyframes images. simply removing `temp/keyframes%03d.jpeg` doesn't work!  Thanks